# output signal now became smaller

Tags: transistors, amplifier

Why is that without the power amplifier block connected to the output of preamplifier, the output signal is ok around 17 volts peak to peak, but if i now connect the power amplifier, the signal somehow attenuates down to around 75% smaller.

This is schematic from pre amplifier block

[image]

and the power amplifier block

[image]

notice that they are connected by the "ww" connector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a quick note of an answer:  the small-signal impedance looking into the base of Q4 is roughly \$(\beta_4 + 1) R_L\$.

This in parallel with the impedance looking into the base of Q5: \$(\beta_5 + 1) R_L\ \$

So, for example, assuming \$\beta = 30 \$ for each transistor, the input impedance of the power amp is roughly \$60 \Omega \$.

The output impedance of your preamp is roughly \$180 \Omega\$.

By voltage division, the loss in the output impedance, due to the input impedance of the power amp is:

\$\dfrac{180}{60 + 180} = 75\%\$

Note:  you can determine the exact AC input impedance of your power amp by driving (just) the power amp with a 1A AC current source.  Plot the AC voltage across the current source.  The value of the voltage is the magnitude of the input impedance.

Note 2:  if, after verifying the input impedance of your power amp, you find it is too low, consider trying a [Darlington](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darlington_transistor) output stage to increase the input impedance:

[image]

Alternatively or in conjunction, add a common-collector stage to the output of your preamplifier to lower the output impedance.

Note 3:  To see an example of a *real* amplifier design, take a look at [The Leach Amplifier](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/mleach/lowtim/).

Comment: Alfred how do I compute for the input.impedance.of my whole amplifier ( with pre and power and speaker combined)????

Comment: The input impedance is dominated by the first stage of the preamp and is roughly R3||R4||(B1 + 1)R2 = 1523 ohms assuming B1 = 99